# How to fix "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm using visual studio code as my IDE for python. However, every time I want to print something in Mandarin, it keep showing me this error "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte". By the way, I've already checked stackoverflow and Google to look for the answer to this question.

I've added the codes below to fix it. In the end, it still failed to fix it.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import io
import sys
sys.stdout=io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')
```

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import io
import sys
sys.stdout=io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import time
import re
def get_web_page(url):
    resp = requests.get(
        url = url,
        cookies = {'over18':'1'} 
    )
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print ('Invalid url:', resp.url)
        return None
    else:
        return resp.text
def get_articles(dom, date):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dom,'html5lib')


    paging_div = soup.find('div','btn-group btn-group-paging')
    prev_url = paging_div.find_all('a')[1]['href']

    articles = []  
    divs = soup.find_all('div','r-ent')
    for d in divs:
        if d.find('div','date').text.strip() == date: 

            push_count = 0
            push_str = d.find('div','nrec').text
            if push_str:
                try:
                    push_count = int(push_str) 
                except ValueError:

                    if push_str == ('爆'):
                        push_count = 99
                    elif push_str.startswith('X'):
                        push_count = -10


            if d.find('a'): 
                href = d.find('a')['href']
                title = d.find('a').text
                author = d.find('div','author').text if d.find('div','author') else ''
                articles.append({
                    'title': title,
                    'href': href,
                    'push_count': push_count,
                    'author': author
                }) 
    return articles, prev_url

def get_ip(dom):
    pattern = '來自 : \d+\.\d+\.\+d\.\+d'
    match = re.search(pattern, dom)
    if match:
        return match.group(0).replace('來自 : ','')
    else:
        return None

API_KEY = '76ec8d187ce0d00ee3fed79ab1b8dc22'

def get_country(ip):
    if ip:
        url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/{}?access_key={}'.format(ip, API_KEY)
        data = requests.get(url).json()
        country_name = data['country_name'] if data ['country_name'] else None
        return country_name
    return None


print('取得今日文章列表…')
PTT_URL = "https://www.ptt.cc"
current_page = get_web_page(PTT_URL+'/bbs/Gossiping/index.html')
if current_page:
    articles = []
    today = time.strftime('%m/%d').lstrip('0')
    current_articles, prev_url = get_articles(current_page, today)
    while current_articles:
        articles += current_articles
        current_page = get_web_page(PTT_URL + prev_url)
        current_articles, prev_url = get_articles(current_page, today)
    print('共 %d 篇文章' %(len(articles)))

    print('取得前 100 篇文章的IP')
    country_to_count = dict()
    for article in articles[:100]:
        print('查詢 IP:', article['title'])
        page = get_web_page(PTT_URL + article['href'])
        if page:
            ip = get_ip(page)
            country = get_country(ip)
            if country in country_to_count.keys():
                country_to_count[country] += 1
            else:
                country_to_count[country] = 1

    print('各國 IP 分布')
    for k, v in country_to_count.items():
        print(k, v)
```

The output of the code above is "line 40
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte"
line 40 is the first line of my code which contains Mandarin.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, what does `chcp` output? Are you sure your code is saved as UTF-8? (Also, try to cut down your code till you have [example])

Comment: you setting sys.stdout as an input?

Comment: @Amadan Yes, I am. It ouputs "使用中的字碼頁: 950".

Comment: @NikkoBobier How to set sys.stdout as an input?  Please be more specific.

Comment: So your console is set to Big5, but you're trying to use UTF-8, so the problem is likely to be somewhere there. I'd guess `-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` tells Python to treat your code as if it was Unicode, but you're saving it as Big5, or something like that. I don't have a Windows at hand to test, though.

Comment: What is line 40?

Comment: @n.m. ```if push_str == ('爆'):```

Answer (score 2):

I just checked - 爆 is represented in Unicode as `0x7206`, which is `0xE7 0x88 0x86` in UTF-8. Your program is complaining about the byte `0xC3` being invalid UTF-8. There shouldn't be a `0xC3` there, unless — you're using Big5, as [your code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_950) suggests. 爆 in Big5 is `0xC3 0x7A`.

Save your code as UTF-8.

Alternately (though I've never tried it, so I have no clue if it works), replace your `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` with `# -*- coding: big5 -*-`.